# what is the Difference between Brushes.Red and new SolidBrush(Color.Red)?

Tags: c#, graph, msdn

Is there any difference between

```
Brush b = Brushes.Red;
```

and

```
Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
```

Because when i use the first constructor i got an exception in drawing the line through the graphics,but it's solved in the second one, i cant figure out the difference???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is not a constructor, it's just getting one of the pre-created objects.

The second one is using the constructor, which means that you are responsible for the object and should dispose it when you are done with it. If you don't dispose it, it will hog a window handle until the garbage collector collects it.

There should be no difference in usage other than that. If you get an exception, it's most likely related to something else that you are doing.

Comment: There is also another difference.  One is a Brush the other is a SolidBrush.  Of course his variable is a brush so it would automatically be downcasted.

Comment: @Ramhound: `Brush` is an abstract class. The properties in `Brushes` returns brushes with a solid color, so they are actually `SolidBrush` instances.